# Making TextBox Clear when user starts typing

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have two text boxes in a win forms that the user will be typing information into. I would like to clear the text box when the user start typing. I am using the `TextChanged` event handler, so every time I type it will erase, which makes me not able to type anything into the text box. Here is the code I am using:

```
private void TXTBX_HourlyRatae_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      TXTBX.HourlyRate.Clear();
      TXTBX.HoursWorked.Clear();
    }
```

I understand that everytime I type into the text box I will be executing this event handler, but I don't know how to go about making it execute only the first time I type into the text box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private bool firsttime = true;

private void TXTBX_HourlyRatae_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (firsttime)
      {
          TXTBX.HourlyRate.Clear();
          TXTBX.HoursWorked.Clear();
          firsttime = false;
      }
}
```

if you want to do it everytime you enter the textbox handle the loss focus event

```
private void TXTBX_HourlyRatae_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }       firsttime = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Move your `Clear()` calls into the corresponding `Enter` or `GotFocus` events.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new private class member:

```
private bool _userHasEnteredText = false;
```

Only erase the text when this bool is false, then set this bool to true once you've cleared the text the first time.